# Is placing an exhausting fan (which works with main electricity) near the hard disk a good idea?

Tags: cooling

Is placing an exhausting fan near the hard disk a good idea? The fan is outside the casing and there is a 3 centimeters gap between the disk and the fan. Will fan's magnetic field have any effect on the hard? The fan works with the main electricity. Not from an adepter. There are few holes in the casing near (opposite the fan's face) where the fan is placed. Details on the fan label is ruined.

In this picture the green box indicates where the hard disk is (inside the casing).

Have heard that magnetic fields can cause hard disks to lose data and shorten it's life span.

[image]

Need to hear more opinions on this.

Comment: "Will fan's magnetic field have any effect on the hard?" - This statement is not clear.  I will be honest your entire question isn't actually all that clear.  I don't see a "yellow box" please provide additional clarification with regards to that.

Comment: Do you need that fan? Why do you have it installed?

Comment: the case is such a samsung  ?'!??@(!?'@-,;. It provides no ventilation at all. The hard temp reaches 65C degrees. The heated air that comes out from the casing is so hot. Power unit also add to this. I badly need some ventilation inside. So I placed this fan to effectively suck out heat.

Answer (score 6):

You don't want to do this.  that setup is *horrifyingly* dangerous. I see bare wires going into a multiple socket that seems to be of legal drinking age. I see electrical taped up joints. I see this whole setup on newspaper and cloth (which is flammable. I'm not sure if the fire would be started by something overheating or sparking though). IF you have a short, chances are you could set your house on fire. That would very likely cause fatal damage to your drive, property and other things.

The fan itself? Dosen't look like a mains fan. You're running 120V into what could be a 5 or 12V fan at possible currents far in excess of its design. It could burn out. It could burn *up*. Its basically a whole load of really really dumb dangerous things all at once.

The fact that you even *need* additional cooling is somewhat concerning, and is a bigger issue than the magnetism. *Heat kills*. But seeing all I've seen? That's less bad than the rest of that jerryrigged deathtrap.

As for the *magnets in the fan*? The hard drive's casing is pretty much designed to magnetically shield the insides. The drive's voice coil? driven by a very strong magnet. Your puny fan's weak magnets would likely have no effect. The housefire you might cause? Very bad.

Comment: the fan has worked for years with the main electricity. So it's not actally 5v or 12v thing. So it might be making a strong magnetic field. That's why I am concerned. I can migrate into a more secure set up. Thanks for the concern.

Comment: Though I have seen a fan that takes 240V AC about that size and dimensions that I pulled out of a photocopier one time The wires don't have to be very thick, as the current is very low, they just need good insulation..

Comment: tbh. I started with the second 2 paragraphs. Then I noticed the fan. And the bare wires going in, and the 'plug' and.... the last two paragraphs got switched over. Maybe its cultural, I've been taught proper respect of electricity (admittedly, I got shocked once) and the reason we use grounded plugs. This set up *scares* me. If its a 220/240V fan (or a 110V fan! Who knows!) I'd want the label on.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no risk. Some disk enclosure got a fan already installed in them.

If the disk need a fan to run I would more worry about the disk warranty. As if it wasnt built-on, why you need a fan on it?

Comment: yeah, usually high speed, whiny, 12v fans IIRC. I wouldn't be suprised if this had one stock come to think of it

Comment: The case is such a samsung ?'!??@(!?'@-,;. It provides no ventilation at all. The hard temp reaches 65C degrees. The heated air that comes out from the casing is so hot. Power unit also adds to this (I have nothing but to hang myself). I badly need some ventilation inside. So I placed this fan to effectively suck out heat.